Installing pyYAML 6.0.2 on RHEL8
I'm trying to install the pyYAML library on a RHEL8 server that doesn't have internet access. Since I can't use pip directly, I'm manually downloading the necessary packages and transferring them to the server. I tried installing PyYAML-6.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl, but the installation fails.
Is there a specific version of pyYAML or a compatible wheel that I should be using for RHEL8? Additionally, how can I ensure that device-specific libraries and dependencies are properly installed on a server with no internet access?
Any help would be appreciated!

Did you check the list of wheel files here https://dl.espressif.com/pypi/pyyaml/ . It seems there are many whl files that support multiple distros.

RHEL 8 includes a packaged version of PyYAML; just grab the python3-pyyaml rpm and install it.

i found a another version which i am able to install, But now there is one more lib safetensore. which I am not able to find the version for RHEL8
